# Why is my cursor offset when using dual screens on VirtualBox 7.0.8 Ubuntu?

Tags: virtualbox, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I'm trying to set up dual screens with VirtualBox. I've got Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS installed with Guest Additions set up. I have enabled the second screen and it created a new window for it, but I cannot change the resolution or order of this second screen without it offsetting the cursor on the first screen.
[An image showing the resolutions and order of the monitors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PjY9.png), it works in this configuration, the cursor is not offset, but as soon as I change the resolution or the order of the second monitor (it should be on the right side), the cursor gets offset for both screens. I also don't seem to be able to select the correct screen resolution for my second screen which should be 3440x1440.

I've tried to fix it with solutions mentioned in [How to fix mouse cursor out of sync with VirtualBox Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952911/how-to-fix-mouse-cursor-out-of-sync-with-virtualbox-ubuntu-server-16-04-3-lts-vm) and other sources, sadly to no avail.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?