# How to calibrate my mouse, Ubuntu is now unusable

Tags: 22.04, virtualbox, mouse

When just started Ubuntu, the mouse is not accurate anymore. To find out what is the difference, I started OpenOffice Draw, an started to draw a line. The is 70 mm difference between my mouse and where the line is drawn. With a few mm difference you can work, all thought it is annoying. With 70 mm difference Ubuntu is just unworkable.

In the past I calibrated the mouse to click in the up left corner. But that does not work anymore.

I used Ubuntu 22.4 within Virtualbox.

Comment: Thanks, I used the answer of ahmegen, and will repeat it here for the future reader.

    In Virtualbox → Machine Settings → System → Motherboard I changed Pointing Device to "PS/2 Mouse"

    In the hosted Ubuntu VM (Xubuntu in my case) go to Mouse and Touchpad change "Device" to "VirtualBox mouse integration"

Comment: @Terrance, could you change your comment to an answer, then I can accept your answer. And add some points to it.

Comment: Instead of duplicating answers, we actually will vote to close them so that others reading along it will help them to that answer as well.  Make sure to give points where the answers or questions helped you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix mouse cursor out of sync with VirtualBox Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952911/how-to-fix-mouse-cursor-out-of-sync-with-virtualbox-ubuntu-server-16-04-3-lts-vm)

Comment: @Thanks Terrance, I did vote for that answer.